# autoencoder for cifar 10 with low accuracy

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I am building a convolutional autoencoder where the objective is to encoded the image and then decode it. However , I am always getting around accuracy: 61% - loss: ~ 0.0159. Following is my code. I am not using Batch normalization or dropout. I am not sure how I can improve the accuracy.

```
#define the input shape
input_img = Input(shape = (img_width, img_height, img_channels))

# convert to float32 format
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')

# Normalize the data
x_train = x_train / 255
x_test = x_test / 255


x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (x)

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2)) (x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2)) (x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2)) (x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2)) (x)
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), padding='same') (x)

cae = Model(input_img,decoded)
cae.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss ='mse', metrics=['accuracy'] )
cae.summary()

history = cae.fit(x_train,x_train,
       epochs = 25,
       batch_size = 50,
       validation_data = (x_test, x_test))
```

Comment: Have you considered that your autoencoder does regression, while accuracy is a metric only valid for classification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the particular images you are encoding, it may be unreasonable to expect to achieve higher accuracy than that. You perform downsampling (`maxpool2D`) 4 times, roughly reducing the number of bits of data by a factor of 16. An auto-encoder is essentially a compression algorithm where the compression strategy / encoding space is learned. Generally, compression algorithms can only hope to achieve 1:3 compression or thereabouts losslessly, so to expect much higher from an autoencoder may not be reasonable.

That being said, your use case may be over a tightly constrained set of images (e.g. static camera so background is the same for all images, etc.). In this case you might expect to achieve high accuracy despite a relatively large compression factor. My guess is that CIFAR 10 is a bit too large of an input space to be able to faithfully reconstruct images at your level of compression.

Answer (score 0):

Higher accuracy can be achieved by reducing the compression ratio. In my previous code, I have eliminated one `MaxPooling2D` and one `UpSampling2D` then my accuracy increased to 70%. Following is the modified code snippet.  Higher accuracy doesn't mean, higher performance. Since I am just compressing and decoding the image, it all depends on the compression ration and final objective.

```
#define the input shape
input_img = Input(shape = (img_width, img_height, img_channels))

# convert to float32 format
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')

# Normalize the data
x_train = x_train / 255
x_test = x_test / 255


x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (x)
# removed 
#x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (x)

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2)) (x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2)) (x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2)) (x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (x)
# removed 
#x = UpSampling2D((2, 2)) (x)
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), padding='same') (x)

cae = Model(input_img,decoded)
cae.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss ='mse', metrics=['accuracy'] )
cae.summary()

history = cae.fit(x_train,x_train,
       epochs = 25,
       batch_size = 50,
       validation_data = (x_test, x_test))
```